# Creating virtual host with nginx

Tags: nginx

I am having a problem with the virtual hosts using nginx
no matter what I do I get to www/html and not the www/example1 folder.
Can anyone please spot the problem? 
Am I missing something?

```
pi@homeserver:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled $ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 467 Sep  4 19:41 default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  38 Sep  4 19:43 example1 -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/example1
```

default file is

```
server { 
  listen 80; 

  root /var/www/html; 
  index index.php index.html index.htm; 

  server_name localhost; 

  location / { 
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404; 
  }

    location ~\.php$ { 
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; 
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$; 
        fastcgi_index index.php; 
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off; 
        try_files $uri =404;
         include fastcgi_params; 
    }
}
```

example1 file is

```
server { 
  listen example1.com:80; 

  root /var/www/example1.com; 
  index index.php index.html index.htm; 

  server_name example1.com www.example1.com; 

  location / { 
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404; 
  }

    location ~\.php$ { 
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; 
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$; 
        fastcgi_index index.php; 
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off; 
        try_files $uri =404;
         include fastcgi_params; 
    }
}
```

i get this error in logs

```
2016/09/04 21:41:08 [emerg] 1788#0: invalid host in "http://www.example1.com:80" of the "listen" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example1.com:2
```

Comment: Are config files from sites-enabled directory included in main nginx configuration? Have you checked output of 'nginx -t' command? Have you reloaded nginx after adding new vhost?

Comment: config files from sites-enabled are not in main nginx configuration? im not sure where that is and never saw this step in any tutorial could you please tell me where should i link these files to? nginx -t is OK, i realoded and even rebooted and still get the www/html folder

Comment: Files from that directory may be loaded perhaps in Debian or at least in some linux/unix.. But at least in CentOS and RHEL that is not the case. You should check nginx.conf, which probably is located in /etc/nginx/. And you should tail your nginx logs same time you are accessing the site, you can see a lot from the logs.

Comment: this is what I see in access log: 
10.0.0.138 - - [04/Sep/2016:21:16:35 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.138 - - [04/Sep/2016:21:16:35 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "http://www.example1.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Well I cant see anything wrong currently in your configs or in that log... Maybe you should test with some simple files in both www roots. Like file with "<h1>default</h1>" as content in the default site etc...

Comment: Thanks @StefanR I'm not sure i understand what you mean but I have wordpress files ready to be installed in the www/example1 folder and just an index.html file in the www/html so once it will be directed as it should I won''t miss it... 
this problem is killing me for 2 days now.. still can't figure it out :(

Comment: Added an error found in the log...

Comment: Try using `listen 80;` rather than `listen example1.com:80;`

Comment: YES!!!! it Worked!!! finally!@#!@# thank you!

Comment: @RichardSmith or Daniel, could one of you post an answer if you found a solution please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, it seems that `nginx` is having difficulty resolving the statement `listen example1.com:80;` to an IP address.

Providing an IP address to the `listen` directive is useful if you have a multihomed server and wish to restrict services to one interface.

In the majority of cases, the statement `listen 80;` will suffice. I suggest you use the following for both server blocks:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) for more.